# MVC server-side fields validation without model in void method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Help please, is there any way to organize server-side textbox fields validation inside void method? Parts of code below:

Main void method:

```
// Add new row into SQL DB
public void AddNewRow(MyClass obj)
{
    bool fieldsValid = CheckFields(obj);

    if (fieldsValid)
    { ... // It's Ok, save new row
}

// Check fields values method
public bool CheckOTKFields(MyClass obj)
{
    bool result = true;

    if (obj.ObjectProperty % 2 == 0 || !(obj.ObjectProperty is int))
    {
        @ViewBag.Otl1_DividingError = "Error description";
        result = false; // Flag to false
    }
    ... // Other properties
    return (result);
}
```

I've tried @ViewBag variables but there are many of difficulties when page is loading\refreshing. May be you know any better way? Or I have to use client-side (js\jQ) validation only?

Comment: What "many difficulties" did you have?  In what way does your code not work as intended?

Comment: @David, I'm a bit confused by 'NULL' exceptions and ViewBag variables declarations in view and controller code..

Comment: "I'm a bit confused" isn't really a specific problem we can address.  If you're getting an actual error, then reading the error message and looking at the code which throws the error would be a good start.

Comment: @David, I just thought that it's 'uncomfortable' way to work

Comment: There's clearly a language barrier here, that last statement doesn't really make sense.  But in any case, you're still going to need to describe the problem if anybody is to help you with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you return a response from the POST action, you could set:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Description");
```

The first parameter refers to a specific property of the model, but empty string works.  The response from the POST will show in the validation summary results.

The difficulty is that it cannot undo any prior actions you've taken; you have to ensure the validation is done on all of the items first and then once safe continue with whatever operation you want to perform.